# How to enable this functionality in windows server 2008?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

How to make the zone transfers occur whenever a change occurs in the zone data. How to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You want to enable DNS notify, and specify the secondary servers to get the update.  This is found in the zone properties, on the zone transfers tab.  If you are using Active Directory Integrated zones, the updates will automatically replicate to the other AD DNS servers that host the zone with the Active Directory replication.